# Why is the following SQL query erroneous?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
/* erroneous query */
select dept name, ID, avg (salary)
from instructor
group by dept name;
```

I know that every non-aggregated function must appear in group by if it appears in select. However this query still runs in mySQL.

should it be:

```
/* erroneous query */
select dept name, ID, avg (salary)
from instructor
group by dept name, **ID**;
```

Because I ran the both queries and they give the exact same answers!

Comment: Is the department name (?) unique? Maybe it works because grouping by the unqiue name and grouping by the ID are the same...

Comment: I would HIGHLY recommend you not use spaces in your column names. There is no good that can come from this. Instead of having to bracket all of your queries to assure that they don't break. What you should instead do is use caps to bookend things. `DeptName` for example easy to read without messing up your database.

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
select [dept name], ID, AVG(salary)
from instructor
group by [dept name]
```

Now it would be more instructive to show the columns defined in your table, but you CANNOT have spaces in a column name without the column being wrapped in brackets live I did above.

Comment: sorry i was suppose to write dept_name. Im just wondering why ID neds to be put in group by as well as dept_name considering that it is dept_name that is what the info is being grouped by?

Comment: When you GROUP, every column in the SELECT MUST either be in the GROUP clause OR an AGGREGATE.  Think about it...

Comment: Ok, that's how it is in SQLServer.  If that's not the case in MySQL (even though it doesn't make sense) then you don't need to put ID in the GROUP

Comment: Ok but generally even if ID etc is put in group by then it is the first function e.g. dept_name that is declared in group by that the data will be grouped by?

Comment: @Andrew you may not need to in mysql however that doesn't make the logic of the query any less broken even if it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: The order of the columns in the GROUP BY dictate what "breaks" the group, in SQLSERVER you can have multiple columns in the GROUP BY, I would think the same is true in MySQL

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean by breaking the group?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will allow you to not include non-aggregated columns in your group by, which is just a terrible idea to me. This can result in some very un-predictable results.  Here's a link to the documentation:
[Clicky!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) on this particular point:

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to non-aggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause. For example, this query is illegal in standard SQL
>   because the name column in the select list does not appear in the
>   GROUP BY ...
>
> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group.

So roughly spoken the omitted columns get added automatically.

However, note that it **is not exactly the same**. Have a look at [this example](http://renormalize.org/post/24114561260/mysql-curious-features-non-deterministic-group-by).

```
SELECT name, address, MAX(age) FROM customers GROUP BY name, address;
```

might give you something different as:

```
SELECT name, address, MAX(age) FROM customers GROUP BY name;
```

Check [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17bc8/5).

Answer (score 0):

Your statement that "I know that every non-aggregated function must appear in group by if it appears in select" is according to me correct. I am not a SQL guru but thats my understanding too. I would have expected a syntax error to be flagged if your statement does not meet that condition. However, if it gives the same result, then the one possibility is that you have the same value in all rows for the ID field or whatever field it is that is missing in the group by list. Just check different values and see. Also, it may help to expressly use "as" for alias rather than blanks.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL [extends the use of GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) so you can select nonaggregated columns, not named in the group by clause:

```
SELECT   dept_name, ID, avg(salary)
FROM     instructor
GROUP BY dept_name;
```

the previous query is perfectly valid in MySQL, while other DBMS will rise an error because of ID not present in the group by clause.

However, if there are more than one ID for each dept_name, the value of ID returned by MySQL will be undetermined.

You can configure MySQL to [disable this extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).